# Node.js / Socket.io Manage crash server (message system)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Hey hello guys :) I have done a message system with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) , [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) and [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/fr) all is working fine but i have a question :

Do you have any idea how i can manage the fact that the server crash and when it restart the message that have been send during the crash status will be send.

That's my first time using all this technologies (even java script) so i am looking for any idea or documentation, because i have 0 idea.

Thx for all that will help :)

Comment: If the server crashes, the websocket connection is instantly terminated. You'll have to handle this client-side, trying to send a message to the server for dispatch, and if the server is offline, then the client keeps retrying until the server gets back online.

Comment: Ok thx for this track i will search some documentation for this :)

Comment: And how can i reconnect users without refreshing ?